# Touch screen not work on Qt Embedded

Tags: qt4, embedded, embedded-linux

I have configured a Qt development environment to develop applications for ARM based Embedded Linux platform. I am using a Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit) host system and beaglebone black ARM hardware platform. I have created a simple hello world program with a button which I have deployed to the Embedded Linux device (BBB) but the touch screen is not working. Below is the code.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QPushButton btn("Hello World");
    btn.show();
    btn.showMaximized();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Any thoughts on what might be wrong?

I used the following tutorial to configure the development and target machine

- [Building and setting up Qt environment for BeagleBone](http://www.cloud-rocket.com/2013/07/building-qt-for-beaglebone/)
- [Setting up Qt Creator for C++ ARM Embedded Linux Development](http://derekmolloy.ie/beaglebone/qt-with-embedded-linux-on-the-beaglebone/)

Comment: Is tslib installed (try runiing ts_calibrate) ?

Comment: @Mali Thanks, I ran  opkg install qt4-embedded qt4-embedded-plugin-mousedriver-tslib everything started to work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before start your program try:

QWS_MOUSE_PROTO=LinuxInput:/dev/input/event0 (or Event1, Event2)

and then run your program